# Passing optional parameters in a batch script

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to write my first batch script and trying to understand how to pass arguments. It's a very simple command which runs fine in *cmd*.

Command:
`C:\Program Files\Foo> myexe -sd tempVar >> C:\temp.txt`

Here *-sd* is command option and *tempVar* is another parameter (I know this tempVar value and can hard code in batch script).

**Batch Script**
`Start "C:\Program Files\Foo\myexe.exe" -sd tempVar`

**Error** While executing about batch file, I get an error stating **-sd** is not recognized. Please suggest what should I work/correct in this script?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter to the `start` command is text to display in the window's title bar, and this value is in quotes.  So, in your case, `start` thinks you want the window title to say **C:\Program Files\Foo\myexe.exe**. Then, you're passing `-sd tempVar` to the `start` command, and it has no idea what that means, as they are not valid parameters for `start`.

Try this instead...

```
Start "" "C:\Program Files\Foo\myexe.exe" -sd tempVar
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick. Silly mistake on my part. Got output on Console, now going to work on redirecting output to a text file.

Comment: Also, if you want to do anything else AFTER that line in the batch file, you might want to add the /wait function, or the batch file will continue doing what it's doing before your exe file has finished it's job: `Start /wait "" "C:\Program Files\Foo\myexe.exe" -sd tempVar`